# Set selected Menustrip item equal to ComboBox value and vice versa

Tags: c#, event-handling

Basically I have a menustrip with 3 items. And another combobox with those exact same three items.

How do I set it so upon clicking an item on one list it sets the other list to the same value.

I hope I explained this clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the ComboBox SelectedItem based on the MenuItem selection You can follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** You need to cast the `sender` object into `ToolStripMenuItem` in your `ToolStripMenuItemClick` Event handler.

**Step 2:** then assign the above casted one into ComboBox.FindString() method as an argument so that it returns the Matching Item index in the `Combobox`.

**Step 3:** now assign the returned Index value by the FindString() method to the ComboBox1.SelectedIndex property so that the exact  item selected in MenuStrip willbe Selected in Combobox aswell.

Try This:

```
item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
item2ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
item3ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(ToolStripMenuItem_Click);

private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString(((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Text);
}
```